# Programmcrash after importing the haarcascade

Tags: c#, emgucv, haar-classifier

I am using `EmguCV`(I don't know the exact Version) and `C#`.

I have created my own haarcascade along to the many tutorials found online, But when it comes to using it inside my own code, I fail. I am using the cascade with this code, but somehow the program just ends itself without any errormsg when it comes to exact that line.

```
HaarCascade LicencePlate = new HaarCascade(Cascade);
MCvAvgComp[] Positives = LicencePlate.Detect(grayFrame);     // The Line it crashes
if (Positives.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (var _positive in Positives)
    {
         Image<Bgr, Byte> tmp = frame.Copy();
         frame.ROI = _positive.rect;
         frame.Draw(_positive.rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 0);
    }
}
```

Also, in case it might help, here are the params of my classifer

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<opencv_storage> 
<cascade>   
<stageType>BOOST</stageType>     
<featureType>HAAR</featureType>   
<height>21</height>   
<width>100</width>   
<stageParams>
<boostType>GAB</boostType
<minHitRate>9.9900001287460327e-001</minHitRate>
<maxFalseAlarm>1.0000000149011612e-001</maxFalseAlarm>
<weightTrimRate>9.4999999999999996e-001</weightTrimRate>
<maxDepth>1</maxDepth>
<maxWeakCount>100</maxWeakCount></stageParams> <featureParams>
<maxCatCount>0</maxCatCount>
<featSize>1</featSize>
<mode>ALL</mode>
</featureParams>  
<stageNum>10</stageNum>
```